# Simulate directory existence during development

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm developing a python application over Windows. However, this application will be deployed in Linux systems.

This application will have a configuration file at `/etc/myapp/config`. This path is not possible in Windows.

So, my question is:

- In Python, is there any way to simulate, only during development process, the existence of a certain directory and file (such as `/etc/myapp/config`)?

Thank you.

Comment: Not an answer to the question but why not start up a vagrant box or a docker container and save yourself the trouble?

Comment: I now, but that is my last choice by the moment

Comment: Just avoid hardcoding any path in your app and you will be fine. Hint: environnement variables and/or command-line arguments are canonical ways to avoid harcoding environnement-dependant values/

Comment: Use a dedicated env var for the "root" dir of your app (with a default value mapped to /etc/whatever)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to "simulate" some non-existant path, just avoid hardcoding any path in your app and you will be fine.

Hint: environment variables and/or command-line arguments are canonical ways to avoid harcoding environment-dependant values. You can read environment variables from the `os.environ` mapping.

This being said, if your app is going to be deployed on some linux distro, you should REALLY test it on the same distro to make sure there are no other glitches. It's not a valid reason for hardcoding your config path (even native linux apps don't and rely on either env variable and/or command line args), but there are quite a few other differences between a unix-like and windows...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of strugling with `/` vs. `\` - just use os.path.join(). 

(read `os.path.join(path, *paths)` in `https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html`).

Then, in your code - use:

```
os.path.join('', 'etc', 'myapp', 'config')
```

And it would work both for `C:\etc\myapp\config` (on Windows) and `/etc/myapp/config` (on *nix).